# How to make limitation on value input field with js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning js and I need help to solve this problem.
My problem is that I try to limit the maximum and minimum value of the input, the adding and subtracting buttons are fine, however, I want when I input numbers directly in the input field if the number greater or smaller than the limitation it will automatically return the limit range.

for example, my limit range is from 1 to 10, when I input 11 into the input field it will return 10 immediately.

I have html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default minus">
    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
</button>
<input id="qty2" type="text" value="1" class="qty" size="5" name="quantity" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-icon add">
   <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

and my js code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.add').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < 10) {
                $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
            }
        });
        $('.minus').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
                $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just make your input type `number` rather than `text` then set attribute `max="10"` ? Atleast there are buttons automatically added by browsers for increment and decrement options for number inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the html `input` tag of `type="number"` if you expect a user to write numbers, and you don't need javascript to limit the min and max values. You simply need to add the attributes to the html tag instead.

```html
<input id="myNumber" type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Considering that you asked **how to do it with javascript**, here is a demonstration with the `onchange` event

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose a number between 1 and 10</p>
<input id="myNumber" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: using html that much easier than I thought.
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use onchange event.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
Like

```
<input id="qty2" type="text" value="1" class="qty" size="5" name="quantity" class="form-control" onchange=onInputChange(this)/>

...
function onInputChange(input) {
   if (input.value > max) {
     input.value = max;
   } else if (input.value < min) {
      input.value = min;
  }
}
...
```

I did not verify the code, but it should be like this. You also can add events like onblur to verify the value of the input.

Comment: The least you could do is verify the validity of your answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer
I also solve my problem with your method